# How to verify RAID1 on my server Poweredge R210?

Tags: raid, ubuntu-16.04, dell-poweredge

I've configured RAID1 through Lifecycle Controller, then I installed Ubuntu 16.04.3. In section partition disk I selected Guided - use entire disk, I'm not sure if I need to configure RAID1 here or it's enough from what I did in LIfecycle Controller?

I'm not sure if I did it rightly but how can I verify if my RAID1 works (if second drive is mirrored)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the RAID controller shows a RAID 1 virtual disk and the Operating System sees a single physical disk then you've set it up correctly. You don't need to do anything in the Operating System because the RAID controller is managing the RAID array.

If you have the iDRAC installed and configured in the server you can verify the RAID configuration under the storage node in the IDRAC.

Comment: +1 Even without iDRAC, you can use `omreport storage vdisk` to show the array level (eg: RAID1), status and other properties.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but one more thing, when I tried to verify RAID1 by disconnected one drive it didn't boot to my OS, it behave like it's empty. Why is that?